# Creating a checkbox programmatically using Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, checkbox

I need to create a checkbox programmatically in Cocoa and when I try and make a button with `buttonType` set to `NSSwitchButton` it displays the title, but does not show the button as a checkbox.  I think I am missing something but I can't find any resources about making things like checkboxes without using the Xcode GUI.

Comment: Not sure why the question has been marked as localized. The votes on both the question and answers show it has value. It's definitely a relevant topic for Cocoa programmers, and not a narrow situation. Creating controls in code with the Cocoa frameworks is very useful in a number of situations.

Answer (score 44):

The question is a little old so you've probably already figured it out, but I found it while searching for this exact thing. Alex danced around the solution without actually providing it. So here, for Google and all mankind: how to programmatically create a checkbox in Cocoa.

```
NSRect frame;
frame.size.width = frame.size.height = 18;
NSButton *myCheckBox = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[myCheckBox setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
[myCheckBox setBezelStyle:0];  // This is unnecessary. I include it to show that checkboxes don't have a bezel style.

[myView addSubview:myCheckBox];
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think buttons are bezeled by default when created programmatically. Check the `setBezelStyle:` method, as well as `setBezeled:` and `setBordered:`. One of those should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had failed to execute setImagePosition properly and this was causing the checkbox not to display.